# Curl to okhttp conversion

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I have a curl of the form `curl -v -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json"........`

Not able to crack how to get the `-u` part working. Have tried multiple options like

```
Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                String credential = Credentials.basic("username", "password");
                return response.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build();
            }
        };
```

and

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();
                RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("username", "password").build();
                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
```

Both of which are not working. Not able to get it working even by posting it as header. Please help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by this.

```
protected Authenticator getBasicAuth(final String username, final String password) {
        return new Authenticator() {
            private int mCounter = 0;

            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (mCounter++ > 0) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
                    return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

then added this as authenticator to my client.